# Webpack doesn't transpile to ES5

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have already done some research and tried different configurations of webpack. However, webpack won't compile my ES5+ code to ES5. In my node_modules directory I have a bunch of babel directories:

- babel-preset-env
- babel-preset-es2015
- babel-core
- babel-helpers
- babel-helper-{lotsOfDifferentDirectories}
- babel-plugin-{lotsOfDifferentDirectories}
- @babel
- @babel/core
- @babel/preset-env
- and many many more...

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./_assets/js/src/example.js"
  },
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "_assets/js/build"),
    filename: "exampleBundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      query: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "jkk-onepager",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://10.8.1.1:850/root/jkk-onepager.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

**src/example.js**

```
let testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

testArray.forEach( item => {
  console.log(item);
})
```

**part of exampleBundle.js**

```
/***/ "./_assets/js/src/example.js":
/*!***********************************!*\
  !*** ./_assets/js/src/example.js ***!
  \***********************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

eval("var testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];\ntestArray.forEach(function (item) {\n  console.log(item);\n});\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./_assets/js/src/example.js?");

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

Console output after I run `npm run build`

```
Hash: 70c0ea4134e6e46211b5
Version: webpack 4.29.6
Time: 896ms
Built at: 2019-03-21 11:28:05
           Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
exampleBundle.js  3.94 KiB     app  [emitted]  app
Entrypoint app = exampleBundle.js
[./_assets/js/src/example.js] 93 bytes {app} [built]
```

Has somebody else faced this issue before? I have tried out every suggestion I could find in articles about this issue, but it didn't help. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Its transpiling your code if you check your `exampleBundle.js` the `let` keyword has been transpiled to `var`

Comment: I am highly confused. So the code is not working on an old iPad (i think iOS 9.3.5) but I don't get any errors. Is the transpiled code supposed to be in this eval()?

Comment: And you are right, `let` has been transpiled to `var`, but shouldn't `forEach` be transpiled to `for(i = 0; i <= testArray.length; i++){...}`?

Comment: `forEach` is already supported by ES5 so theres no need to transpile it. [check this link](https://caniuse.com/#search=foreach)